# Concatenate styles in SL 4 / WPF?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wpf-controls

How can I use several styles on a control?
For example, I have a style that defines the size and margins for buttons, and several styles that define different color schemes.  I would like to use the sizing style and a colors style on one control.

Any hints are appreciated...
Thanks.

Comment: Related question:  When defining a style, how you incorporate an existing control template?

Comment: When you say "control template" do actually mean "data template"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Silveright you can't combine multiple styles and apply them to a control. The closest that you can natively get is the `Style` `BasedOn` property where you can take an existing `Style` and extend it with additional setters.  However there is no simple way to declarively (or even dynamically) combine two or more existing Styles to create a "combined" style.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look in to BasedOn.